# how can we use a document template for a library?

Tags: 2013, document, library, word

We are having a requirement in which we need to assign a word template to a document library.

I know that we can assign doc file to be template of the document library. But that brings up a new blank word doc.

Instead I want the word doc to have some data like firstname, last name, dob, etc. So user can click on new document, then a word doc with above data pops up, then user can enter his details.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If clicking a new document gives you a blank document, you must have assigned a blank document as a library document template. You can go to library settings -> advanced settings and customize the template there. You can also use document panel to quickly edit document properties.

However if you want to have document specific data ready for editing, i suggest using content types. As a general reference to do that:

1. Create a content type in site settings -> site content types.
2. Customize the content type by adding the specific columns.
3. Assign a template for that content type. It can be done in the advanced settings of the content type.
4. Go to the library and enable content type management. In library settings -> advanced settings.
5. Once you enable content types in the library, add your previously created content type to the library.

You can find detailed instructions on how to create and add content types on our website:
http://www.enovapoint.com/SiteAssets/jungledoc-documentation/index.html?CreatingContenttypes.html

Using content types is always suggested. Now once you click a drop down for a new document you will be able to select a content type. Once you select it, your content type template will be shown and you will be able to customize it. You can show document information panel to quickly edit document properties.

To always display document information panel:

1. In you word client click Developer tab. You might need to enable it first.
2. Click Document Panel button.
3. In the new window check "Always show Document Information Panel on document open and initial save"

Now once you open a new document, you will be able to quickly fill on document properties. Those properties are columns in your content type. You can also use quick parts for quick document customization. In your word document template click Insert -> Quick Parts -> Document Property -> select a column.

These placeholders will copy document properties to the document itself once you open it, or update document properties using document information panel.